# How do you fix unity cube collisions when moving on a unity by unit basis?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, collider

I am currently making a 3D cube maze game in unity where you have to navigate through the maze from one location to another in the least amount of moves possible.

At the moment I have set it out so that the cube is controlled by using the arrow keys on your keyboard but the cube only moves unit by unit. So depending on the direction that you want the cube to move in the code is set up to add a unit in that direction.

My collisions are working but not as I want them to work, when you play the game the cube does collide with the outer maze wall barriers and is automatically moved back to the original position, so for example is I am moving forward and I reach the point of the barrier and I press the forward key again the cube moves to the new position and then realizes that there is a wall there and is moved back. if I press the arrow key twice quick it jumps to the outer part of the maze which I do not want. I want the cube to stay inside of the maze so to only allow movement with in the maze.

How do I stop this from happening?

The way I move my cube is.

```cs
if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyKode.UpArrow))
{
     transform.position += Vector3.forward;
}
```

it has something to do with the above code because if I change the movement to not be unit by unit then the colliders work fine.

Any help please

Comment: You probably need a [raycast](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Physics.Raycast.html) to check if the cube can move or not

Comment: Also you can use Rigidbody [MovePosition](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody.MovePosition.html) instead of transform, this method caculate collision before move the cube so it's a simple solution